# BUILD FAIL ON HEROKU

Tags: python, numpy, heroku

Trying to deploy a python application on Heroku, however it fails in building with the following log:

```
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy, pandas, scikit_learn, tornado, blinker, validators
      Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): started
      Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): still running...
      Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

...

```
     × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
     │ exit code: 1
     ╰─> [1133 lines of output]

     note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
     ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
     Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): started
     Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
     Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
     Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
           error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Here is what the requirements.txt file looks like:

```
gspread<=5.4.0
numpy<=1.19.2
oauth2client<=4.1.3
pandas<=1.4.2
scikit_learn<=0.24.1
streamlit==1.10.0
```

Would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Probably would be better to use a Heroku buildpack for numpy https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/andrewychoi/heroku-buildpack-scipy . MOre info about buildpacks https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was simply not deploying to Heroku. Given the work itself was based on streamlit. Just went ahead to deploy the application on Streamlit-Cloud with no-single-issue.

Not sure if this totally qualifies as an answer.